# FFT of an Audio Buffer

Tags: javascript, audio, web-audio-api

How do I take the FFT of an AudioBuffer using WebAudioApi ?

```
AudioBuffer {length: 8575407, duration: 178.6543125, sampleRate: 48000, numberOfChannels: 2}
length: 8575407
duration: 178.6543125
sampleRate: 48000
numberOfChannels: 2
__proto__: AudioBuffer
```

Visualization Doc calls for stream insted of a buffer

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API/Visualizations_with_Web_Audio_API

```
source = audioCtx.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
source.connect(analyser);
```

Update

```
  console.log(buffer);

  source = audioCtx.createBufferSource(buffer);
  source.connect(analyser);
  analyser.connect(audioCtx.destination);

  analyser.fftSize = 2048;
  var bufferLength = analyser.frequencyBinCount;
  var dataArray = new Uint8Array(bufferLength);

  analyser.getByteTimeDomainData(dataArray);

  console.log(analyser);
```

conosle

```
AnalyserNode {fftSize: 2048, frequencyBinCount: 1024, minDecibels: -100, maxDecibels: -30, smoothingTimeConstant: 0.8, …}
fftSize: 2048
frequencyBinCount: 1024
minDecibels: -100
maxDecibels: -30
smoothingTimeConstant: 0.8
context: AudioContext {baseLatency: 0.01, destination: AudioDestinationNode, currentTime: 8.04, sampleRate: 48000, listener: AudioListener, …}
numberOfInputs: 1
numberOfOutputs: 1
channelCount: 2
channelCountMode: "max"
channelInterpretation: "speakers"
__proto__: AnalyserNode
```

Comment: I imagine that you'd have something like `source = audioCtx.createBufferSource();` in your code ... you can `source.connect(analyser)` and `analyser.connect(audioCtx.destination)`

Comment: I'd also imagine you would "play" the sound so it can be analysed and initialise the analyser before connecting it